# Changing image basing on color, wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamicresource

I've got the following scenario. Somewhere there is a `DynamicResource` with color. This color determines background of windows and basing on that color I want to choose right icons to display (bright or dark).

I imagine the following scenario:

- The color changes, triggering a change in my class
- My class checks, which icon set should be chosen
- It forces all users of these icons to reload them.

I guess, that this should be doable using WPF mechanisms. The problem is, that I don't quite know, how to build architecture, which will do such processing.

1. Capturing color change. I guess, that I can write a class with a `DependencyProperty` called, say, `BackgroundColor` and then attach that color through a `DynamicResource`. This way I can capture the color change using the `PropertyChangedCallback`.
2. Internal processing is easy.
3. I have to expose my icons, such that they will be attachable through the `DynamicResource` mechanism. How? By some kind of collection? Each one by its own DependencyProperty?
4. I have to notify all users of these icons, that they have changed. How? By IObservableCollection? Calling NotifyPropertyChanged on each property representing an icon? Maybe in some other way?

If there's a simpler way to achieve the goal I presented, I'll gladly hear it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create a light and a dark [WPF Theme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#styling_themes) and then switch between them dependant on the colour currently set as the `background` colour. Using this method, WPF will take care of all of the icon updates.

If you want to create your own system, you can use the `DependencyProperty` system to help you:

#### `Background` colour is changed:

You can simply add a `PropertyChangedCallback` handler to the current `Background` property:

```
static YourControl()
{
    Control.BackgroundProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(YourControl), 
        new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.White, OnBackgroundChanged));
}

private static void OnBackgroundChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // The Background property value changed
}
```

#### Exposing Icons and notifying the UI:

You can create a class that holds a `string` property to data bind to each `Image.Source` property in the following format:

```
"\ApplicationName;component/ImageFolderName/ImageName.FileExtension"
```

As long as this class implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, then all you need to do is to change these `string` values and the UI will automatically update with the new icons or images.

Comment: How may I switch between themes depending on color? By switching between themes I understand choosing different ResourceDictionary and that indeed would solve my problem. But I have no idea when to trigger the change (in terms: in some class? By binding with converter?) and how to perform this change...

Comment: Please see the [Switching WPF interface themes at runtime](http://svetoslavsavov.blogspot.co.uk/2009/07/switching-wpf-interface-themes-at.html) article on Svetoslav Savov's Blog.